# JUnit test of the same object

Tags: java, serialization, object, junit

I want to make a unit test suite of the same object with same variable but different values. However if the object get the same name (created by `this.setName("testlaunch");` (we must have the name of a method tested by JUnit), it runs only one test.

If i don't write  `this.setName("testlaunch");` it complains saying `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: TestCase.fName cannot be null`.
I don't know what to do...

```
public class LanceurRegleGestion extends TestSuite
{
    public static Test suite()
    {
        Class maClasse = null;
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        String filtre = ".*.xml";
        // on compile le pattern pour l'expression réguliere
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(filtre);
        String path = "D:/Documents/workspace/Solipsisme/src/ReglesGestion/XML/";
        // on liste les fichiers du repertoire
        String [] u = new File(path).list();
        // on parcours la liste de fichier
        System.out.println("Initialisation");


        for (int i=0; i

et le code de l'objet serialisé



public class Application extends TestCase {
private String nomappli;
private String id2_1;
private String id3_1;
private String id4_1;
private String id2_2;
private String id3_2;
private String id4_2;
private String id5_2;
private String id6_2;
private String id7_2;
private String id8_2;
private String id9_2;
private String id2_3;
private String id3_3;
private String id4_3;
private String id2_4;
private String id3_4;
private String id4_4;
private String id2_5;
private  String id3_5;
private String id4_5;
private String id5_5;
private String id6_5;
private String id7_5;
private static Selenium selenium;
public Application(String nomappli,String id2_1,String id3_1,String id4_1,String id2_2,String id3_2,String id4_2,String id5_2,String id6_2,String id7_2,String id8_2,String id9_2,String id2_3,String id3_3,String id4_3,String id2_4,String id3_4,String id4_4,String id2_5, String id3_5,String id4_5,String id5_5,String id6_5,String id7_5)
{
this.setName("testlaunch");
this.nomappli = nomappli;
this.id2_1 = id2_1;
this.id3_1 = id3_1;
this.id4_1 = id4_1;
this.id2_2 = id2_2;
this.id3_2 = id3_2;
this.id4_2 = id4_2;
this.id5_2 = id5_2;
this.id6_2 = id6_2;
this.id7_2 = id7_2;
this.id8_2 = id8_2;
this.id9_2 = id9_2;
this.id2_3 = id2_3;
this.id3_3 = id3_3;
this.id4_3 = id4_3;
this.id2_4 = id2_4;
this.id3_4 = id3_4;
this.id4_4 = id4_4;
this.id2_5 = id2_5;
this.id3_5 = id3_5;
this.id4_5 = id4_5;
this.id5_5 = id5_5;
this.id6_5 = id6_5;
this.id7_5 = id7_5;
}

public Application(){

}
public String toString()
{
return getNomappli();
}
public void setNomappli(String nomappli)
{
this.nomappli = nomappli;
}

public String getNomappli()
{
return this.nomappli;
}
public void setId2_1(String id2_1)
{
this.id2_1 = id2_1;
}

public String getId2_1()
{
return this.id2_1;
}
public void setId3_1(String id3_1)
{
this.id3_1 = id3_1;
}

public String getId3_1()
{
return this.id3_1;
}
public void setId4_1(String id4_1)
{
this.id4_1 = id4_1;
}

public String getId4_1()
{
return this.id4_1;
}
public void setId2_2(String id2_2)
{
this.id2_2 = id2_2;
}

public String getId2_2()
{
return this.id2_2;
}
public void setId3_2(String id3_2)
{
this.id3_2 = id3_2;
}

public String getId3_2()
{
return this.id3_2;
}
public void setId4_2(String id4_2)
{
this.id4_2 = id4_2;
}

public String getId4_2()
{
return this.id4_2;
}
public void setId5_2(String id5_2)
{
this.id5_2 = id5_2;
}

public String getId5_2()
{
return this.id5_2;
}
public void setId6_2(String id6_2)
{
this.id6_2 = id6_2;
}

public String getId6_2()
{
return this.id6_2;
}
public void setId7_2(String id7_2)
{
this.id7_2 = id7_2;
}

public String getId7_2()
{
return this.id7_2;
}
public void setId8_2(String id8_2)
{
this.id8_2 = id8_2;
}

public String getId8_2()
{
return this.id8_2;
}
public void setId9_2(String id9_2)
{
this.id9_2 = id9_2;
}

public String getId9_2()
{
return this.id9_2;
}
public void setId2_3(String id2_3)
{
this.id2_3 = id2_3;
}

public String getId2_3()
{
return this.id2_3;
}
public void setId3_3(String id3_3)
{
this.id3_3 = id3_3;
}

public String getId3_3()
{
return this.id3_3;
}
public void setId4_3(String id4_3)
{
this.id4_3 = id4_3;
}

public String getId4_3()
{
return this.id4_3;
}
public void setId2_4(String id2_4)
{
this.id2_4 = id2_4;
}

public String getId2_4()
{
return this.id2_4;
}
public void setId3_4(String id3_4)
{
this.id3_4 = id3_4;
}

public String getId3_4()
{
return this.id3_4;
}
public void setId4_4(String id4_4)
{
this.id4_4 = id4_4;
}

public String getId4_4()
{
return this.id4_4;
}
public void setId2_5(String id2_5)
{
this.id2_5 = id2_5;
}

public String getId2_5()
{
return this.id2_5;
}
public void setId3_5( String id3_5)
{
this.id3_5 = id3_5;
}

public String getId3_5()
{
return this.id3_5;
}
public void setId4_5(String id4_5)
{
this.id4_5 = id4_5;
}

public String getId4_5()
{
return this.id4_5;
}
public void setId5_5(String id5_5)
{
this.id5_5 = id5_5;
}

public String getId5_5()
{
return this.id5_5;
}
public void setId6_5(String id6_5)
{
this.id6_5 = id6_5;
}

public String getId6_5()
{
return this.id6_5;
}
public void setId7_5(String id7_5)
{
this.id7_5 = id7_5;
}

public String getId7_5()
{
return this.id7_5;
}

public void setSelenium(Selenium selenium)
{
this.selenium = selenium;
}

public Selenium getSelenium()
{
return this.selenium;
}

public final static void login()
{
    selenium.open("apj/ident");
    selenium.type("username", "hsuzumiya-cp");
    selenium.type("password", "1");
    selenium.click("enterButton");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("9999999");
}

public void  testlaunch()
{
    generique(this.nomappli,this.id2_1,this.id3_1,this.id4_1,this.id2_2,this.id3_2,this.id4_2,this.id5_2,this.id6_2,this.id7_2,this.id8_2,this.id9_2,this.id2_3,this.id3_3,this.id4_3,this.id2_4,this.id3_4,this.id4_4,this.id2_5,this.id3_5,this.id4_5,this.id5_5,this.id6_5,this.id7_5);
}
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Initialisation");

    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("127.0.0.1",4444,"*iexplore", "http://hsuzumiya/");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.setTimeout("90000");
    selenium.setSpeed("500");
    login();
}



public void generique(String nomappli,String id2_1,String id3_1,String id4_1,String id2_2,String id3_2,String id4_2,
    String id5_2,String id6_2,String id7_2,String id8_2,String id9_2,String id2_3,String id3_3,String id4_3,String id2_4,
    String id3_4,String id4_4,String id2_5, String id3_5,String id4_5,String id5_5,String id6_5,String id7_5
)
{
    System.out.println(nomappli);
    selenium.click("valider");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("validertout");
}


public final void tearDown() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Killing session");
    selenium.stop();
}


}
```

Comment: It is hard to follow your description of the problem. Can you post the stack trace for the assertion that is failing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being new to junit, I stumbled upon this question hoping to solve a problem I had getting the same message.  Through further research, I found that it is necessary to pass the name of the test function you want to invoke through addTest to the constructor of the test case class.   A simple (and useless, other than illustration) example follows:

**JunitTestCases.java**

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
public class JunitTestCases extends TestCase {
    public JunitTestCases(String fnName) {
        super(fnName);
    }
    public void testA() {
        assertTrue("assertTrue failed", true);
    }
}
```

**JunitTestSuite.java:**

```
import junit.framework.*;

public class JunitTestSuite {
    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(new JunitTestCases("testA"));
    return suite;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run(suite());
    }
}
```

When I compiled with:

> javac -cp .:*path/to/junit-X.X.X.jar* JunitTestSuite.java

and ran with

> java -cp .:*path/to/junit-X.X.X.jar* JunitTestSuite

this worked with no errors, with junit giving me an OK message.